# How to handle vulnerability CVE-2018-1258 while using Spring Security Version 5 with Feign Client(latest version)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud-feign

In our project, we are using Spring security version **5.1.5.RELEASE** and I want to use the Feign clients(currently we have Spring cloud OpenFeign) to implement the clients for other Rest APIs.

But the security check says a HIGH severity vulnerability **[CVE-2018-1258](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2018-1258)** which is because we are using Spring Security 5 with lower version but these are one of the latest versions available.

Spring Dependencies right now -

```
ext.springBootVersion = "2.1.6.RELEASE"
ext.springCloudVersion = "2.1.3.RELEASE"
ext.springSecurityVersion = "5.1.5.RELEASE"

"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}",
"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:${springBootVersion}",
"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:${springBootVersion}",
"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas:${springBootVersion}",
"org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:${springBootVersion}",
"org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:${springCloudVersion}",
"org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-security:${springCloudVersion}"
```

Is there any way to work this out or do I have to remove the Feign client and implement it on my own?

Answer (score 4):

Ideally this shouldn't be applicable to your case, As per Spring https://pivotal.io/security/cve-2018-1258,

> **Mitigation**
>
> - Users leveraging Spring Framework 5.x should avoid using Spring    Framework 5.0.5.RELEASE. Updating to Spring Security 5.0.5.RELEASE+
>     or Spring Boot 2.0.2.RELEASE+ brings in Spring Framework
>     5.0.6.RELEASE+ transitively. However, users should be certain that other dependency management mechanisms are also updated to use Spring 
>     Framework 5.0.6.RELEASE or newer.
> - Users leveraging Spring Framework
>     4.x (Spring Security 4.x or Spring Boot 1.x) are not impacted so no steps are necessary.
> - There are no other mitigation steps required.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I am also wondering as the Spring boot version is also **2.1.6.RELEASE** and I do not know how to escape this other than implementing the client using something else..

Comment: how did you identify this vulnerability , is your code raising this issue or you used some tool like blackduck to scan for vulnerability

Comment: we are using dependency check (https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-check-gradle/index.html) and our pipeline fails when the vulnerability score is higher than 7.

Comment: There could be some transitive dependency causing this, but this is just my guess , run following command mvn dependency:tree  -Dincludes=spring-security and see if there is any other version of spring security etc, if you find nothing then generate  dependency tree using mvn dependency:tree, and still you don't find anything mark this issue as false positive

Comment: just realized you are using gradle so use dependency tree command related to gradle.

Comment: Yeah I did that and there is nothing with 5.0.5 at all

Comment: well notify the issue to dependency-check@googlegroups.com with your dependencies and move on

Comment: Yeah I have just suppressed the vulnerability and will do the mail as well. Thank you very much for your help. 

Comment: spring core 5.0.6 compatible with 5.0.5 ?

Comment: yes it is , Spring follows Semantic versioning so it is compatible, read more at  https://semver.org/

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't directly relate to `Feign Client`, but it relates to `CVE-2018-1258` false positive.

***This is only when using gradle dependencyCheck plugin. There is an [issue on github](https://github.com/jeremylong/DependencyCheck/issues/2558).***

Latest "Spring Boot (2.3.0)" at the moment, which under the hood utilizes "Spring Security 5.3.2" shows false positive:

```
spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar (pkg:maven/org.springframework.security/spring-security-oauth2-resource-server@5.3.2.RELEASE, cpe:2.3:a:pivotal:spring_security_oauth:5.3.2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*, cpe:2.3:a:pivotal_software:spring_security:5.3.2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*, cpe:2.3:a:pivotal_software:spring_security_oauth:5.3.2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*) : CVE-2018-1258
spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar (pkg:maven/org.springframework.security/spring-security-oauth2-jose@5.3.2.RELEASE, cpe:2.3:a:pivotal:spring_security_oauth:5.3.2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*, cpe:2.3:a:pivotal_software:spring_security:5.3.2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*, cpe:2.3:a:pivotal_software:spring_security_oauth:5.3.2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*) : CVE-2018-1258
spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar (pkg:maven/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web@5.3.2.RELEASE, cpe:2.3:a:pivotal_software:spring_security:5.3.2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*) : CVE-2018-1258
spring-security-oauth2-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar (pkg:maven/org.springframework.security/spring-security-oauth2-core@5.3.2.RELEASE, cpe:2.3:a:pivotal:spring_security_oauth:5.3.2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*, cpe:2.3:a:pivotal_software:spring_security:5.3.2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*, cpe:2.3:a:pivotal_software:spring_security_oauth:5.3.2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*) : CVE-2018-1258
spring-security-config-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar (pkg:maven/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config@5.3.2.RELEASE, cpe:2.3:a:pivotal_software:spring_security:5.3.2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*) : CVE-2018-1258
spring-security-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar (pkg:maven/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core@5.3.2.RELEASE, cpe:2.3:a:pivotal_software:spring_security:5.3.2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*) : CVE-2018-1258
spring-security-crypto-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar (pkg:maven/org.springframework.security/spring-security-crypto@5.3.2.RELEASE, cpe:2.3:a:pivotal_software:spring_security:5.3.2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*) : CVE-2018-1258
```

The vulnerability states it is only related to 5.0.5.